# TableViewController - one key value offset to the others

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I've got a problem with my TableViewController. I'm posting 3 values to the tableViewController. A scoreID, a scoreDate, and a scoreValue. It all seems to work correctly, but my problem is, that the scoreValue is offset by 1 to the scoreID and Date. It's easier to show with a picture:

[image: As you can see the top cell isn't populated with the score.]

("A good business idea" Should have the value of "another good idea" and so on and and so on)
Now, I know from looking in the .sqlite database file, that the scores are offset by one. So my question is how to fix it?

My tableViewController.m looks like this:

```
#import "CEWTableViewCell.h"

@interface CEWScoreTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger countOfRows;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *scoreIDsForTableCells;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fetchedObjects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *getScoreDataToDict;



@end

@implementation CEWScoreTableViewController{
    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat topLayoutGuide = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topLayoutGuide, 0, 0, 0);

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;


    [self.tableView registerClass:[CEWTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    //INITIALISE APPDELEGATE AND CREATE INSTANCE. MAKE FETCH REQUEST AND POPULATE DATA TO NSDICTIONARY
    CEWAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ScoreData" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchRequest == nil) {
        NSLog(@"an error occured fetching objects...!");
    }


    NSLog(@"objectForKey returns: %@", self.scoreIDFromEntity);






    NSUInteger countIDsForRows = [self.fetchedObjects count];
    self.countOfRows = countIDsForRows;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

//This value is set to the number of @"scoreID"s returned
    return self.countOfRows;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellID";

    CEWTableViewCell *cell = (CEWTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CEWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    self.getIndexPath = indexPath.row;


    NSDictionary *getScoreIDs = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSDictionary *getDates = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //This is just formatting the date to the format I want displayed
    NSDate *pullDates = [getDates valueForKey:@"scoreDate"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:pullDates];

    //Here I fetch the @"scoreValue"s and convert them from a string, so I can add them up
    NSDictionary *getScoreValues = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *convertDictKeyToString  = [getScoreValues objectForKey:@"scoreValue"];

    NSArray *items = [convertDictKeyToString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        double total = 0.0;
        for (NSString *string in items)
        {
            total += [string floatValue];
        }
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [getScoreIDs objectForKey:@"scoreID"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = formattedDate;
    cell.tableCellScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f", total];

    return cell;
}
```

I hope this is enough code, otherwise let me know, and I will try and provide more

**ANSWER**

Sooooooo. It turns out, that my labels was offset because of the CGRect x,y,x,y values.... Ehrm...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called really fast so it doesn't have a lot of time to perform calculations, and for what I've read formatters take more resources than what you think.

I usually solve this issue by creating a new method that gets called from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, and in this method I create an array or some sort of container for the data I need.

Then cellForRowAtIndexPath only has to call the array by indexes.

Comment: Sooooooo. It turns out, that my labels was offset because of the CGRect x,y,x,y values.... Ehrm... Anyways... I appreciate your answer, and I did refactor my code to make it a bit leaner and better performing... I will come back and upvote your answer when I get the rep to do so! Thanks for taking your time to answer, and sorry for being daft! Cheers

Comment: Haha, no problem man. Im glad you were able to find the issue anyways